# Simulate how a transaction will affect state before it is mined

Tags: transactions, txpool

My program needs to know how the transactions in the mempool will affect the state when mined. Does anyone know of any tools to help with this? I know I can do it manually with ganache --fork, but I don't know a good way to automate it without starting from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can interact directly with the `ganache-core` library: [github](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-core#usage)

Below is a test with using the infura API. This also works with a local node.

```
const ganache = require("ganache-core");
const Web3 = require("web3");

// set whatever options you'd use in the cli here
const options = {
  fork: "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/API_KEY",
  port: 6546,
};

const server = ganache.server(options);
const provider = server.provider;
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

web3.eth.getBalance("0x635B4764D1939DfAcD3a8014726159abC277BecC")
.then(console.log);
web3.eth.getBlockNumber()
.then(console.log);
```

---

[image]